# Why is my StackNavigator not showing anything?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm creating a React Native app, and I want to use Stack Navigator from React Navigation (I've done this before, so I'm not totally new to it).  However, when I add in the Navigator, nothing renders.

My component is:

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, ScrollView, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {AppProvider} from './src/stores/app-context';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppProvider>
        <SafeAreaView>
          <ScrollView>
            <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </AppProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

This just shows a blank screen.

However, if I add the `HomeScreen` component directly, it works:

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, ScrollView, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';

import {AppProvider} from './src/stores/app-context';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppProvider>
        <SafeAreaView>
          <ScrollView>
            <HomeScreen />
          </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </AppProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

In this second case, it shows the text 'Home Screen', as expected.

`AppProvider` contains this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppReducer} from './app-reducer';
import {IAppState, IAppAction, INIT_STATE} from './app-types';

const AppContext = React.createContext<{
  appState: IAppState;
  appDispatch: React.Dispatch<IAppAction>;
}>({
  appState: INIT_STATE,
  appDispatch: () => null,
});

const AppProvider = ({children}: any) => {
  const [appState, appDispatch] = React.useReducer(AppReducer, INIT_STATE);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{appState, appDispatch}}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export {AppContext, AppProvider};
```

(`IAppAction`, `AppReducer` etc are just interfaces etc; I don't believe they're relevant).

I'm clearly doing something wrong, but I can't see what it is.  Can someone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, ScrollView, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';

import {AppProvider} from './src/stores/app-context';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppProvider>
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
          <ScrollView>
            <HomeScreen />
          </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </AppProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Adding **flex to SafeAreaView** with start showing home screen

Comment: Thank you! I also moved the ScrollView to inside the HomeScreen component, so one of those 2 things fixed it!